# How to deal with client on requirement?

Tags: software-development, project-management, developer, time-management, clients

I am software developer and the client gave me some requirement.

So, the topic is I know that the requirement which is given by client will take too long to implement/finish and it will cost more budget. Now, the client does not understand my approach which is much easier than doing it his way.

For example:

The client requirements is to switch on the fan so the client want to take 1 stick and then after using that stick you have to turn on the fan using switch and stick. but my requirements is simply you can use your own mobile to switch on the fan.

So, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write down the client requirements, add your time and cost estimation.
Write down your proposal, add your time and cost estimation.

Ask for confirmation that you understood the client requirement correctly (which is easier when it's written down) and ask for confirmation that the client wants the old idea implemented over the new idea.

In your wording, take care to decouble those plans as much from persons as possible.

Don't say: "My idea, your idea".

Say: "Existing idea, new idea"

That way, it's psychologically easier to accept the new idea.

Whichever ideas gets accepted, implement that. Since you clarified, there should be no surprises afterward.

Answer (score 3):

Your job is to advise your client and then to do what they ask, and what they're paying you for.

You advised them that your requirement is more efficient. They've rejected your requirement. The solution is very simple; you can either do what they ask and what they're paying you for, or you can fire them as a client.

Stop trying to impose your will on your client.

Comment: Upvoted for the first paragraph; the other 2 paragraphs come off as a bit aggressive, can they be worded a bit nicer?  I agree  with what you're saying, but the verbiage is a bit...

Comment: They're not aggressive statements. They're matter of fact and to the point. Being direct and vehement doesn't equate to being aggressive. Consultants should either abide by the wishes of their client or they should fire their client. Consultants should not impose their will on the client. I see this all of the time.

Comment: Appreciate you answer but it's seems like to not co-operate with client requirement  in second paragraphs i want to deal with client requirements not to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

> is given by client will take too long to implement/finish and it will cost more budget

There is no such thing as too long and too much cost, it's just a matter of them paying for it. You give professional advice, if that is ineffective you do it their way at whatever extra cost it will take. There may be valid reasons you are unaware of for the way they want it done, or not, but either way they're the ones paying.